# How to create a List<String> from a List<Map<String, String>> in Dart?

Tags: collections, dart, flutter

I have a `Map` that looks like this

```
{
    title: "Hello world",
    images: [
        { url: "http://example.com/image1" },
        { url: "http://example.com/image2" },
        { url: "http://example.com/image3" }
    ]
}
```

and I need a `List<String>` of the images that looks like this

```
[
    "http://example.com/image1",
    "http://example.com/image2",
    "http://example.com/image3"
]
```

My current code looks like this

```
List<String> images = [];
if( map['images'] is List<dynamic> ) {
    map['images'].forEach((v) {
        if (null != v['url'])
            images.add(v['url']);
    });
}
```

It works good, but I am curious if there is a one-liner that would accomplish the same thing in a neat (and error safe) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
var images = map['images'].where((m) => m['url'] != null).map((value) => value['url']).toList();
```

First we select all the items from `map` that do not contain a `null` field for `url`. Then we map these `url` values to a new `List`.

Comment: I prefer this solution, as it checks that the `url` key actually exists and the value is non-null!

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = map['images'].map((innerMap) => innerMap['url']).toList()
```

Comment: Smooth solution.